# Issues with nested route navigation and non loading http-mock

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Hello I have a router with this:

```
   goToMessagesView: function () {
      this.transitionToRouter("app.messages");
    }
```

Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The route app.messages was not found

However if I use:

```
   goToMessagesView: function () {
          this.transitionToRouter("messages");
        }
```

I navigates to http://localhost:4200/app/messages, but I expected it would go to http://localhost:4200/messages.

my router:

```
  this.route('app', function () {
    this.resource('fo', {path: 'fo/fo_id'});
    this.resource('messages');
```

If I navigate to 'http://localhost:4200/app/messages' it works but doesn't load the model from my http-mock as is in the route:
 app/messages:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.find("messages");
  }
});
```

Comment: message is a resource. use this:  `this.transitionToRoute("messages")` ... also `transitionToRoute()` is for controllers... for routes, it is more appropriate to use `transitionTo()`

Comment: @Grapho I changed the action to : this.transitionTo("app.messages"); but I get The route app.messages was not found

Comment: this.transitionTo("messages")

Comment: @Grapho ok, but I am calling it from localhost/ so I don't understand why I don't need to append the transition with .app